# Generating dynamic css into custom file

Tags: functions, theme-options

This is about running code on wordpress . The given code runs properly outside wordpress but when I put it on theme functions file it does not do anything.

```
ob_start();
require('dynamic-css.php');
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$f = fopen("custom.css", "w");
fwrite($f, $content);
fclose($f);
```

I think I have to put this inside custom function and add hook then.

Comment: You have to understand WordPress' file structure, have a look at the [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) function, try what it produce and see how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look a the 'Using a Hook' on here:

[WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I found a way

```
add_action( 'init', 'run_this_code', 1 );
function run_this_code() {
ob_start();
require('dynamic-css.php');
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$f = fopen("custom.css", "w");
fwrite($f, $content);
fclose($f);
}
```